# Append to an existing route JS and Larvel

Tags: javascript, laravel, url, routes

I'm trying to append to an existing Laravel route with JS without having to build a URL object.

My route is in the HTML element below.

```
<div class="clickable-element js-location-id" data-href="{{ route('report.file.list')}}">DATA</div>
```

Here is my JS function that builds the new URL. Currently, the new URL is hardcoded, but I'd prefer to grab the existing route from the html element  and just append the id to it, so if I ever update the route, I don't need to update the JS.

```
buildTileFilter(){
        //Can I grab the route from the html element without having to create a url?
        let url = new URL('http://sample_site/report/file/list?f%5B%5D');
        let query_string = url.search;
        let search_params = new URLSearchParams(query_string);
        search_params.set('f[]', this.locationId);
        url.search = search_params.toString();
        let new_url = url.toString();
        return new_url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to get the value of the data attribute into the JS function?

you can just use vanilla JS to retrieve the value from the element.

So if you had an ID on the element you could just use document.getElementByID('the-ID-of-the-element').dataset('href');

Answer (score 0):

You could also bypass the need for creating an element for the purpose of holding the value if the JS is in you blade template file. You can simply use blade interpolation to inject the route directly in your code like so:

```
buildTileFilter(){
    //Can I grab the route from the html element without having to create a url?
    let url = '{{route('report.file.list)}}';
    let query_string = url.search;
    let search_params = new URLSearchParams(query_string);
    search_params.set('f[]', this.locationId);
    url.search = search_params.toString();
    let new_url = url.toString();
    return new_url;
}
```

Comment: I get an error if I do this. The console says "Cannot create property on search on string '{{route('report.file.list')}}';